# Update (increment) value when Parse Object is retrieved?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Is there a way to update a Parse Object field (increment) before it is returned from a Parse Query or retrieve method?

An example is for a view count to be incremented every time it is returned.

I've looked at `beforeFind` method but it looks like it is just for modifying queries before it is executed.

Comment: If you want to display the view count in the UI, i guess after retrieving from Parse, you can just increment the value by one and display it, and save it back to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a cloud function to handle the query instead of calling the query directly from the client.  In the find() success handler, iterate through and increment that value, call a Parse.Object.saveAll on the results, and then return all the results in the response.success() call.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such way that modifies the values you retrieve from queries. You can only edit the query statement. If there is a need to modify the value into DB, you have to retrieve first, update the table, then return back the incremented value.